# How an absolute import finds the root directory?

Tags: python

I am confused in Absolute imports definition. It says:

`Absolute import involves full path i.e., from the project’s root folder to the desired module`

Suppose I am having a structure:

```
App
  project1
    file1.py
    file2.py
    __init__.py
  project2
    file3.py
    file4.py
    __init__.py
```

If from file `file3.py` I have to import some functions from `file1.py`, then I will write as

```
from app.project1.file1 import someFucntion
```

Question: How python finds that app is my root directory. My file structure can be different. I may have multiple folders above `App` folder.

Like `/Users/Nitesh/App/Project1` --> This may be my directory structure

Does Python consider root directory from a point where there is no `__init__.py`?

Comment: Python looks at the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to find the "root". Don't forget to put an `__init__.py` in each folder.

Comment: @byxor: I do not think this is the right answer. I have not touched PYTHONPATH. If this is the case then it should work with only directories mentioned in the PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 3):

Well how I understand it is that you should start execution from the root directory. That way python inserts the current working directory into `sys.path`, which is the project root directory.